# Are there any quality of life add ons for Content Admin page? Easier sorting, searching, etc

Tags: views

I think the words make it vague for a google search since I'm not really finding anything. Looking for enhancements to the Content screen in Admin (that lists all of your content items). You can search for things and sort by a few select fields but looking to expand this and make it more specific to our content types. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers. Research and testing needs to be done before asking a question. Please describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Please have a look at the help section and learn which questions are [on-topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and which [off-topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on Drupal Answers. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The content page is actual just a view.  You can just edit it to make it do what you want to.  This is set up via the initial site creation so you will not loose your changes when core is updated.